# Sprint Boot Default Login Page should be overridden

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement spring security and the default login page is being displayed even though i have login page with url defined in controller as "/login"

Spring boot version : 2.0
Spring version: 5.0

Have two classes one for spring MVC config and another for Spring Web Config

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the configure method within your spring security like the following:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.jsp");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can direct to jsp directly or to a controller managed url

In the configuration class:-

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.jsp");
}
```

Or like this:-

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login");
}
```

And creating a url **`/login`** in your **`@Controller`** class